# Upgrading from sde 9.2/oracle10g to sde 10.2/oracle11g

Tags: arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I have an old geodatabase created using Arcsde 9.2 on Oracle 10g.

Now, I'm trying to update it to new system using ArcSDE 10.2 on Oracle 11g r2.

Because SDE 9.2 schema and SDE 10.2 are not compatible with each other, I tried to setup a transition stage through ArcSDE 10.0.

ie: SDE 9.2/Ora 10g ---> SDE 10.0/Ora 10g ---> SDE 10.2/Ora 11g r2

What I did:

1. I made two vmware machines with win2003 installed on both, the first named `dbserver` and the second named `sdeclient`
2. On `dbserver`, I installed Oracle 10g.
3. On `sdeclient`, I installed Oracle client 10.2, ArcGIS Desktop 10, ArcSDE 10.
4. I creted new database named `testdb` On `dbserver` [while the original database name `calgarydb`].
5. I exported `calgarydb` from the real system and imported it to `testdb`.
6. I tested connection through oracle client on `sdeclient` to `dbserver` and it was succeeded.
7. From ArcCatalog 10.0 I tried to use direct connection to `testdb` on `dbserver` using the following parameters:

   - Server  : none
   - Service : sde:oracle10g:testdb
   - Database: none
   - Username: system
   - Password: pass
   - Connection details: sde.DEFAULT

but I received the following error:

`Failed to connect to the specified server.`
`Operation Failed [Connection failed when attempting to connect using a 10.0 direct connect driver to 9.2 geodatabase. Missing suitable direct connection driver for this connection type. Please install the 9.2 direct connection driver. ArcSde Direct Connect driver release - 100001; ArcSde database instance release - 92011; ArcSde low release for instance - 92005]`

Any idea please.

Comment: There is no reason for two machines. You should not **EVER** connect via ArcSDE as SYSTEM.  The error message is quite explicit -- Did you try installing a 9.2 client?

Comment: Thank you @Vince for reply,
I didn't get what you mean by `installing a 9.2 client`. do you mean installing arcsde 9.2 service?

Comment: No.  Early Direct Connect clients were not as flexible as recent releases -- You'd need the appropriate software for a 10.x client to connect to 9.2.  All in all, I think you'd be better off exporting to a 9.2 file geodatabase, upgrading it with Desktop, then importing to a new geodatabase.

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration is not the best candidate for an *in-situ* upgrade.  Given the distance of four major ArcGIS releases (and more than a dozen minor releases), and three major Oracle releases, plus operating system compatibility issues, your most reliable migration path would be to:

1. Use 9.2/9.3 Desktop to convert your 9.2 geodatabase tables to file geodatabase, then
2. Upgrade the 9.x file geodatabase with a 10.x Desktop client, then
3. Import the 10.x file geodatabase to a new enterprise geodatabase in Oracle 11gR2

If the old feature classes are badly spatially fragmented (e.g., they appear to draw in random order), and you have an Advanced (ArcInfo) license of Desktop, it would likely be wise to use the [Sort (Data Management) geoprocessing tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000057000000) with a spatial sort method to defragment at least the larger tables (those exceeding 50k features) before importing into the new geodatabase.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll follow your suggestion and hope it solves the problem.